# Efficiency of retrieving List<T> and casting to different type in a single statement

Tags: vb.net

I was reading [this old article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Tool-Tracker/2015/12/Convert-List-Types.aspx) about how to cast a List of a type to a List of different type.  The original article text is as follows:

> But, because you have a collection of objects, you might assume that
> you have to write a loop and transfer your objects from one List to
> the other individually. The good news is that you can do that in one
> line of code using two LINQ functions: Cast and ToList. Here's the one
> line solution that creates a list of Customers from a list of a
> derived class, PremiumCustomers:
>
> ```
> Dim pCusts As List(Of CustomerPremium) pCusts = GetPremiumCustomers()
> Dim custs As List(Of Customer)
> custs = pCusts.Cast(Of Customer)().ToList()
> ```

Applying this to my own code, I have no use for the first `pCusts` List, except to immediately convert then discard it.  Therefore I shortened to this:

```
var custs = GetPremiumCustomers().Cast<Customer>().ToList();
```

Is my approach any more memory efficient?

I assume so because I wasn't explictly working with two lists, but I'm not sure what happens in the background to generate the final list.  In my own code, `GetPremiumCustomers()` is `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `List<T>`.

Comment: I would expect the compiler to optimize the first code to be the same as the second.

Comment: Even if compiler would not optimize this variable out - the performance hit should be very negligible.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance here - I'd go for what's more readable to yourself and others who might look at the code. Compilers are pretty clever with optimising away stuff like this. More important than a miniscule performance gain is readability (don't get me wrong, performance optimisation is important, but not everything needs optimisation).

Comment: If `GetPremiumCustomers` returns `IEnumerable(Of T)`, then you absolutely should prefer your approach---not because it's more efficient, but because it's more correct.  `GetPremiumCustomers` does not promise that it returns a `List(Of T)`, so you are risking a runtime cast failure if the implementation should ever change.

Comment: The other correct alternative would be to not specify a type on `pCusts` explicitly, so it would then infer to `IEnumerable(Of T)` instead of `List(Of T)`, and then you would have code that is functionally equivalent either way.